# «l'élite» significa «la élite» o «le élite»?

Tags: grammar

> L'Italia è in ginocchio a causa di una pressione fiscale, unicamente finalizzata a mantenere *l'élite*, che è senza precedenti in occidente.

In questa frase «l'élite» significa «la élite» intesa come un'unica entità o «le élite» intese come una pluralità di gruppi di persone?

Cioè, come funziona quel «'» lì?

Answer (score 9):

Qui “élite” è senz'altro al singolare. In italiano contemporaneo l'elisione di “le” è pressoché inesistente. Per citare Serianni, «già cinquant'anni fa Bruno Migliorini osservava che “la forma apostrofata comincia a prendere una sfumatura di sostenutezza, di pretenziosità o viceversa di pronuncia plebea: *l'armi* [...], *l'ali* sanno di letterario, *l'ernie* di troppo popolare”». Migliorini scriveva nel 1938, e la situazione è ormai solidificata come la stava descrivendo.

Answer (score 2):

In italiano si mette l'apostrofo solo nelle parole singolari, in quelle plurali non si usa perché, come in questo caso, potrebbe creare confusione. Ad esempio si dice al singolare l'analisi (= la analisi) e al plurale le analisi, perché altrimenti non sarebbe chiaro.